# Borrar formulario

Tags: javascript

bueno mi pregunta es que debo agregar al javascripr para cuando le de click al submit en este caso me limpe el cuadro de texto que en mi caso es uno solo, o sea el textarea. gracias de antemano
este es mi codigo

```
 <textarea id="user_message_textarea"style="resize:none;height:100px;width:700px;" class="form-control" placeholder="Texto que voy a poner en el placeholder"></textarea>
                                                        <br>
                                                        <button id="user_message_button" type="button" class="button">Enviar</button>
                                                    </center>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                    <div id="snackbar_nuevo_servicio">Mensaje enviado. Gracias</div>
                        <script>
                            var showing_snackbar = false;
                            function user_message_success(){
                                var x = document.getElementById("snackbar_nuevo_servicio");
                                var b = document.getElementById("user_message_button");
                                x.className = "show_nuevo_servicio";
                                b.className = "btn btn-primary btn-md disabled";
                                showing_snackbar = true;
                                setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show_nuevo_servicio", ""); showing_snackbar = false; b.className = "btn btn-primary btn-md";}, 3000);
                            }


                            $("#user_message_button").click(function(){
                            if(($("#user_message_textarea").val()).trim()  !== ""){
                            if(showing_snackbar == false){
                            $.post("user_message.php",
                            {
                            user_message:   $("#user_message_textarea").val()
                            },
                            function(data, status){
                            if(status == "success"){
                            user_message_success();
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            });


                            </script>
```

Comment: Prueba poner el textarea dentro de un elemento `<form>` y cambiar el botón que tienes por un `<input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>` También: El HTML de tu pregunta no es válido. Hay muchos elementos que cierras sin haberlos abierto.

Comment: si es que no puse el html entero porque es muy grande lo puse del boton pa abajo

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que hacer un reset. Es decir:

```
document.getElementById("user_message_button").reset();
```

En caso de no estar en un formulario (porque no veo la etiqueta), puedes "vaciar" si quieres el textarea, es decir:

```
$("#user_message_textarea").val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sencilla de borrar un input es:

```js
$('.borrar').click(function(){
   $('#user_message_textarea').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="" id="user_message_textarea" cols="30" rows="10">Hola Mundo</textarea>
<button class="borrar">Borrar</button>
```